# Spring Boot HATEOAS links wrong when deployed on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I've developed a REST API for an AngularJS application using Spring Boot.  I'm running Java 8 and deploying to Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu, running Oracle's JDK8.  Everything works just fine when I run from within Eclipse, or if I run the application as a JAR.  If I hit localhost:9000/api I'll get output such as:

```
{
    "expenses" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:9000/api/expenses"
    },
    "expenseTypess" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:9000/api/expensetypes"
    },
    ....
}
```

If I package up the application as a WAR and deploy it on Tomcat at /myapplication, I lose the trailing slash after the application root.  Calls to 192.168.1.170:8080/myapplication/api returns:

```
{
    "expenses" : {
        "href" : "http://192.168.1.170:8080/myapplicationapi/expenses"
    },
    "expenseTypess" : {
        "href" : "http://192.168.1.170:8080/myapplicationapi/expensetypes"
    },
    ....
}
```

...which obviously causes everything to explode since none of the API links are correct.  If I manually invoke the correct URI, then the returned resources also have corrupted links.

Has anyone seen this and overcome it?

Comment: We need to see the code that's creating the response.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer was really simple.  So simple, I neglected to even think about it.  I had defined a base URI for the API in application.properties as:

```
spring.data.rest.base-uri=api
```

Changing to:

```
spring.data.rest.base-uri=/api
```

fixed the problem :/