# How do I remove the tomcat context from the urls generated by spring hateoas?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-hateoas

When I deploy a Spring application to tomcat with, say , `/rest` as the context, this prefix is added to the urls generated by spring hateoas, going from, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/games` to `http://localhost:8080/rest/games`. However, this may not be desired if the application is behind a reverse proxy. Spring hateoas respects th `X-Forwarded-Host` header so that the links become like `http://foo.com/rest/games`, but they should be like `http://foo.com/games`.

I've tried looking around stack overflow for headers and spring configuration to do this, but All I could find were methods to **add** a prefix to the links. I also found a spring property `spring.data.rest.base-path` that sounds like it should help(based on questions like [Spring Boot HATEOAS links wrong when deployed on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861200/spring-boot-hateoas-links-wrong-when-deployed-on-tomcat)), but I was not able to make it change anything

The workaround that I am using currently is to make the spring application the root application on tomcat, but this doesn't work well if I want multiple spring applications on the same server. I know I can do multiple tomcat instances, but our current vps is rather scrawny.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue